# Creating an Object in a Class then using it in different class

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create an object in one class then use that object in another class but each time I try to use it it just says the value is null

```
Customer cus = new Customer();
ServerSocket s = null;

public AddCustomer() {
}

public void getCustomerDetail() {
    String back = " ";

    {
        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(5433);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (back.equals(" ")) {
            try {

                Socket s1 = s.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection established at port 5433");
                InputStream is = s1.getInputStream();

                ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                System.out.println("Getting data...");

               cus = (Customer)dis.readObject();
               
                System.out.println(cus.toString());
                System.out.println(cus.getName());
                dis.close();
                s1.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed.");
            } catch (ConnectException connExcep) {
                System.out.println("1Error: " + connExcep.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ioExcep) {
                System.out.println("2Error: " + ioExcep.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("3Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            new AddCustomer().addCustomerToDB();
        }
    }
}

public void addCustomerToDB() {
    System.out.println("start ");
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    int check = 1;
    System.out.println(cus.getName()+"dadawd");
}
```

When I print out the value of `cus.getName()` it just gives me `null` but when I print it out in `getCustomerDetail` it gives me the correct value.
`dis.readObject` returns an object with the values in it.

Comment: We need to also see the code which is calling these two methods.

Comment: You must create your classes inside same package . Also you can create an interface in the same package . Then use `extends` keyword to inherit the other class or use `implements` keyword to  implement the methods in the interface to your preferred class.

Comment: Where is the code for Customer,  mainly getName()?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are doing in the getName function and in the constructor.

Maybe in getCustomerDetails() you are setting the values in the input stream. But the default constructor doesn't do anything with name variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue of packaging. Try below code.

```
public class AddCustomer {  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
new AddCustomer().getCustomerDetail();
}
Customer cus = new Customer();

public void getCustomerDetail() {
    String back = " ";

    {
        while (back.equals(" ")) {
            try {                  
                System.out.println(cus.toString());
                System.out.println(cus.getName());
                System.out.println("Connection closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("3Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            new AddCustomer().addCustomerToDB();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void addCustomerToDB() {
    System.out.println(cus.getName()+"dadawd");
}
}

class Customer{
  private String name="ABC";    
    String getName() {
       return name;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We found here one issue you have to create "Customer cus = new Customer();" this object under main() function like as

```
public class AddCustomer {  
public static void main(String[] args) {
Customer cus = new Customer();
    
new AddCustomer().getCustomerDetail();
}
```